# Google maps SDK

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using Google maps with the following:

```
mapV = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 
                            self.view.frame.size.height) camera:camera];
```

but  when I debug it is showing the following error at least 15 times:

> : CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Then it crashes throwing an exception:

```
[GMSCachedTile setPerTileExpiration:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a01f680'
```

Can anybody please help?

Comment: i think it is not google api error. it looks like you are trying to create a context with invalid frame or parameter. cgcontext must me created in drawRect: method only. once post little more code to understand better.

Comment: It's not necessary to repeat that error as often as you get, once with a note that it is repeating lots of times is enough for this question. Also, use code style for error outputs so it's clearer to see where you are pasting output and where you are writing your own thoughts.

Comment: I have improved the layout of your question for you, but you need to post more code as suggested earlier. Only then can you get help. Use the [edit] button to insert the code into the question.